# C programming, unicode and the linux terminal

Tags: c, linux, command-line, unicode

So what I'm trying to do is write Japanese characters to my terminal
screen using C and wide characters.

The question is whats wrong with what I'm doing so that I can fix it, 
what other caveats  should I expect while using wide characters and 
do you have any other comments about what I'm trying to do?

The bad code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main( ) {
    wprintf(L"%c\n", L"\x3074");
}
```

This doesn't work, but I want to know why.

the problem only gets worse when I try to use a wchar_t to hold a value:

```
wchar_t pi_0 = 0x3074;      // prints a "t" when used with wprintf
wchar_t pi_1 = "\x3074";    // gives compile time warning
wchar_t pi_2 = L"\x3074";   // gives compile time warning
```

So I'd also like to make this work too, as I plan on having data structures
holding strings of these characters.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this question better expressed as "How do I configure my terminal to display unicode?" If so, it probably belongs on SuperUser. In any case, please *do not* post it again on that site. It will either be handled here or migrated by a coalition of high rep users.

Comment: @dmckee the default terminal on any normal linux distro displays unicode. This is a programming question.

Answer (score 10):

The type of `"\x3074"` is `const char[]` and the type of `L"\x3074"` is `const wchar_t[]`.

If you need a `wchar_t`, use single quotes:

```
L'\x3074'
```

Also `%c` prints a `char`, but for `wchar_t` you need a `%lc`.

Answer (score 6):

There are at least two problems in the code.

- the first one has been pointed out by Kenny, the format doesn't match the argument
- the second one is that you miss a call to setlocale()

(There is also the assumption that the wide character set is Unicode -- I seem to remember it is always the case for Linux, but it isn't universal).

In a correctly configured terminal,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main( ) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    wprintf(L"%ls\n", L"\x0152\x3074");
    return 0;
}
```

should work.  If it doesn't, I would start by checking the result of setlocale() and wprint().

(I've added U+0152 which is the OE ligature so that I can check the behavior; I'm not using a font which has U+3074)

Comment: The setlocale call did it for me.

Comment: Why does calling setlocal with an empty local string set the console encoding to UTF-32?