# how to handle russian string as a command line argument in C program

Tags: c

I have an exe file build from C code. There is a situation where russian string is passed as an argument to this exe.

When I call exe with this argument, task manager shows russian string perfectly as command line argument.

But when I print that argument from my exe it just prints ???

How can I make my C program(hence exe) handle russian character?

Comment: You need `unicode` support in your console and in your program for that. In program try using `wchar_t` datatypes if available.

Comment: Compile using unicode / multibyte characters.

Comment: Can you guys give me example of how to combile using unicode/multibyte? I have tried using wchar_t but not helping

Comment: Take a look at [**C programming, unicode and the linux terminal**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231211/c-programming-unicode-and-the-linux-terminal) It appears to address your question (Japanese characters from terminal)

Comment: It is operating system specific.

Comment: `printf("%ws",argv[1])`.

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends on a target platform for your program. Traditionally, a C- or C++-program begins its life from `main(....)` function which may have *byte-oriented* strings passed as arguments (notice `char*` in main declaration `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`). Byte-oriented strings mean that characters in a string are passed in a specific byte-oriented encoding and one character, for example `Я` or `Ñ` in `UTF-8` may take more than 1 `char`.

Nowadays the most wide used encoding on Linux/Unix platform is [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), but some time ago there were other encodings in use such as ISO8859-1, KOI8-R and a lot of others. Most of programs are still byte oriented as UTF-8 encoding is *mostly* backward-compatible with all traditional C strings API.

In other hand wide strings can be more convenient in use, because each character in a widestring uses a predefined space. Thus, for example, the following expression passes assertion test: `std::wstring hello = L"Привет!¡Hola!"; assert(L'в' == hello[3]);` (if UTF-8 char strings are used the test would fail). So if your program performs a lot of operations on *letters*, not strings as a whole, then widestrings can be the solution.

To convert strings from multi-byte to a wide character encoding, you may use [mbtowc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/mbtowc/) functions family or that awesome fancy [codecvt](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/codecvt/) C++-11 facility if your compiler supports it (likely it doesn't as of mid-2014 :))

In Windows strings are also *can* be passed as byte-oriented strings, and for Russian most likely CP1251 is used (depends on Operating system settings, but for Windows sold within Russia and CIS this is the most popular variant). Also MSVC has a language extension which allows an application programmer to avoid all this complexity with manual conversion of bytestring to widestrings, and use a variant of `main()` function which [instantly receives widestrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wd819wh.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

@user3159253 provided a good answer that I will complete with some more references:

- **Windows**: Usually it uses *wide characters*.
- **Linux**: Normally it uses *UTF-8* encoding: please [do **NOT** use wide chars](http://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/manual/html_node/The-wchar_005ft-mess.html#The-wchar_005ft-mess) in this case.

You are facing an internationalization (cf [i18n](/questions/tagged/i18n), [i10n](/questions/tagged/i10n) ) issue.
You might need tools like [iconv](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) for character set conversion, and [gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html) for string translation.

Comment: Well, I would argue that nowadays a lot of programs for Linux/Unix use various toolkits, many of which built around/with widestrings. For example, `Qt`, `wxWidgets` ([wxString](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_string.html)) and many others. Also Python and Java use widestring internally. So I think currently it's Ok to convert from/to bytestrings on input and output, and perform all internal calculations with widestrings

Comment: It works for sure ! However if you have portability constraints, wide chars can be really annoying as their representation can [vary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character#Programming_specifics). But I am talking as a Linux user and C programer :p
The most important is to chose an internal format and stick to it: all strings that come in input shall be converted in this format, and converted back on output if needed.